# Is there a functional way to map a list (N elements) to a list of sums of adjacent elements (N - 1 elements) in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, functional-programming

If it is possible using reduce/fold or other functional ways then I cannot find out how to do that.
I need to somehow transform a list of let's say:
`1, 2, 5, 2`
to
`3 (1+2), 7 (2+5), 7 (5+2)`

I understand the problem is that reduce/fold iterate over adjacent elements but it is only one of the elements that is used with the result of reducing the previous.
If there were a way to iterate over overlapping/intersecting pairs then it would allow for what I need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need is a sliding window of two elements while iterating over the list. You can do it in Kotlin like this:

```
val result = listOf(1, 2, 5, 2)
    .windowed(2) {
        it.sum()
    }
```

result now contains the list `[3, 7, 7]`.

Answer (score 6):

If we target specifically pairs of adjacent items (and not e.g. triples), then Kotlin provides the [zipWithNext](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/zip-with-next.html) function which does exactly this:

```kotlin
listOf(1, 2, 5, 2).zipWithNext(Int::plus) // [3, 7, 7]
```